# How to draw a parse tree?

Tags: parsing, bnf

How can I draw the parse tree for 4*(3+5*7).
The sum of the above expression is 152.
first 5*7=35, then 35+3=38, finally 38*4=152.
I am not sure about what I drew. Please Help. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, perhaps? (pardon my crappy ASCII art skills)

```
    *
  /   \
4      (
      /  \
     +    )
    / \
   3   *
      /  \
     5    7
```

(an AST would omit the parenthesis, not required for evaluation)